# Ionic with local NodeJS backend worker

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, ionic-native, capacitor

I am trying to understand Ionic development for mobile (with Capacitor), and something is off. When I develop Electron desktop app, I have a division for local working backend service and frontend of my choice.

The case is, Ionic apparently doesn't give such option. Of course, I can create online backend on Fireship or Google Cloud, but it would be great to build such thing on mobile. Am I not mistaken? Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Ionic is completely for "front-end", there is no "back-end" when it comes to ionic.